# Value of JSON object on render_template Python

Tags: python, html, json, python-3.x, flask

I have a `profile` method and a profile.html template.

profile.html has a drop-down list of user e-mails. When I select one of them, a modal window appears with this email, and I can send a message to it. I get it via AJAX.

The problem is that `born_date` and `phone_number` of this user, which I get from the database **are not rendered into a template**, and I can not see them in modal window, but I can get them in the console.

```
def str_value_to_list(text: str):
    *_, email_json = re.findall(r'[^ \',()]+', text)
    return email_json

#profile page method
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET','POST'])
def profile():
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'loggedin' in session:
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM users.data WHERE description = 'doctor'")
        account = cur.fetchall()
        description = account
        countries = ['USA','France','Italy','Spain','Australia','New Zealand']

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT born_date, phone_number FROM users.data WHERE email = '%s'" % (dtx, ))
        account = cur.fetchone()
        born = account[0]
        num = account[1]
        print(born)
        print(num)

        return render_template(
            'profile.html', 
            id = session['id'], 
            email = session['email'],
            firstname = session['firstname'], 
            description = description, 
            countries = countries,
            born=born,
            num=num
        )

@app.route('/api/get_data', methods=['POST'])
def get_data():

if request.method == 'POST':
    print('Holy Shit!')
    data = request.json
    print(str_value_to_list(data['selectedItems'][0]))

    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT born_date, phone_number FROM users.data WHERE email = '%s'" % str_value_to_list(data['selectedItems'][0]))
    account = cur.fetchone()
    born = account[0]
    num = account[1]
    print(born)
    print(num)
    return jsonify({
        'born': born, 
        'num': num,
    })
```

`html`

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function printValue(selectedItem) {
        $('#mySelectedValue').html(selectedItem.value);
        }
    </script>
          
   <h2 class="white-text" style="font-size: 14px; color: #000;">born: {{ born }}</h2>
  <h2 class="white-text" style="font-size: 14px; color: #000;">num: {{ num }}</h2>

                          

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function printValue(selectedItem) {
                    $('#mySelectedValue').html(selectedItem.value.replace(/[{()}]/g, '').replace(/['"]+/g, '').replace(/[{,}]/g, ''));
                    console.log(selectedItem.value);
                }
                function process(selectedItem) {
                    $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show')
                    document.getElementById('#exampleModalCenter')
                    const data = JSON.stringify({
                        "selectedItems": $('#sel').val()
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/profile",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: data,
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                    });
                }
                function optionClick(selectedItem) {
                    printValue(selectedItem);
                }
            </script>
```

Comment: @bad_coder, its a bad format of code. It is not working for now.

Answer (score 0):

Per your code, you should use Javascript to update the born and num variable inside your Ajax success funtion:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/get_data",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        h2 = document.querySelectorAll('.white-text')
        h2[0].innerText = `born: ${data.born}`
        h2[1].innerText = `num: ${data.num}`
    },
});
```

You didn't put variable born, num in the render_template function, so you are not able to render it using `{{ var }}`

Comment: it did not help.. I have added `return render_template('profile.html', msg_sent=msg_sent, born=born, num=num)`

Comment: Am I understanding wrong or you are not posting the latest code?

Comment: There is no variable `born` and `num` in your profile function. you should put my code into your Ajax `success` function, and update the Ajax url from `url: "/profile"` to `url: "/api/get_data"`, then see if it works.

Comment: I have added code, I do not how to update Ajax from `url: "/profile"` to `url: "/api/get_data"`. Could you please show on my example? I really do not know how to solve this more than a week

Comment: first time it worked, but after page refreshing id did not work. Could you please check this [link](https://repl.it/repls/MiserableIgnorantInterfaces#main.py). You are the only person, who very close to help me with this issue.

Comment: what do you mean "page refreshing"? your javascript code would re-run after you reload your html page.

Comment: yes. I just refreshed page and can not see my data again. Maybe there wers some changes. Stil can not understand? Could you please see the link with all methods

Comment: It's loading quite slowly, do you have wechat account? maybe we can talk on that.

Comment: @yoxiaoy, I have created a room here from another account and will write from there. Just send some test text check this [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218295/value-of-json-object-on-render-template-python)

Comment: I cannot load your link successfully, it's just showing "Just a second…" and nothing else.

Comment: @yoxiaoy, then could you please create it by yourself, as you have more than 20 reputation